# Extra slashes after conversion of file path to URI using JAVA toURI method

Tags: java, docker, playframework, path, uri

I am using

```
        final File jsonSchemaFile = new File(path);
        final URI uri = jsonSchemaFile.toURI();
```

after using Logger of play framework on path and URI
I used the Logger in this way

```
        Logger.info("path:->"+path);
        Logger.info("uri:->"+uri.toString());
```

I got this output after I start my server with the help of Docker

```
        path:->conf/config_schema/xyz.json
        uri:->file:////rule_engine-1.0/conf/config_schema/xyz.json
```

but I don't want these extra slashes because of this I am not able to pick the xyz.json

I tried all the methods present in URI but I am not able to remove backslashes from the URI

Comment: In what environment are you executing this?

Comment: I am using MacOS when i run this server without docker it runs fine and it is able to pick up the xyz.json file but when i use docker server is not able to pick up the URI path because of these extra slashes

Comment: toString or getPath will offer the absolute path. So you would not be able to use it when running in a container. If using a docker why can this be a configuration parameter?